# emr-containers IAM sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity issue

Tags: boto3, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

When using boto3 (emr-containers) execute `StartJobRun` from an authorized EC2, the job starts and eventually the following log/error manifests:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity operation: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity

---

I've followed the AWS how-to docs provided [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/EMR-on-EKS-DevelopmentGuide/iam-execution-role.html) to ensure that the boto3 client (when submitting the job) includes the ARN of an IAM role that retains an IAM trust policy configured as so (yes, the `---` indicate removed info):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::---:oidc-provider/---"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "oidc.eks.---.amazonaws.com/id/---": "system:serviceaccount:emr:emr-containers-sa-*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

At this point, I'm lost of why this problem is persisting. The job gets submitted (and started) using said role, runs in the proper namespace and transient service account, but regardless of that, the error above still manifests - what are some possible causes and solutions for this?

Comment: As a side-note, I recommend making `emr-containers` a new, useable tag.

Comment: have you found solution for your case? I have a same problem here.

Comment: yes but it seemed to be a matter of not formatting the OIDC string correctly...so, make sure it is set correctly according to the docs and the SAME for `Federated` and `StringLike` values